# Classes are scenes. Trying to repeat the scene if the answer is not consider

Tags: python, class

I think I titled the question really bad, but I can't really think about something better. Sorry about that (also, english is not my first language, so another sorry for my grammatical crimes).

In the ex45 of 'Learn Python The Hard Way', I have to make a text game which some conditions, like use one class per room. I use the code in ex44 (almost identical to the code below) as a prototype, cause I really can't undestand how the three final lines works and interact with everything. I think is too much for a novice in programming like me, I even try to write it down, line by line, following every step.

Plus that, I also try to make the variable `current_scene` so if you introduce an answer not contemplate in the `if` variable, you repeat the scene.

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, map_scenes):
        self.map_scenes = map_scenes

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.map_scenes.open_scene()

        while True:
            print "\n---------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.text()
            current_scene = self.map_scenes.next_scene(next_scene_name)


class Scene(object):

    def texto(self):
        print "Parent class for scenes"

        exit(1)


class Death(Scene):

    types = [
        "You're death.",
        "You pass away."
    ]

    def text(self):
        print Death.types[randint(0, len(self.types)-1)]

        exit(1) 


class Again(Scene):

    repeat = [

        "Can you repeat?",
        "Try again.",
        "One more time."
    ]

    def text(self):
        print Again.repeat[randint(0, len(self.repeat)-1)]
        print current_scene     # =/


class Intro(Scene):

    def text(self):

        print "The intro scene"

        return 'start'


class Start(Scene):

    def text(self):

        print "The first scene"
        print "Where do you want to go?"
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "bear":

            return 'bear'

        elif next == "valley":

            return 'valley'

        elif next == "death":

            return 'death'

        else:

            return 'again'


class Bear(Scene):

    def text(self):

        print "The second scene."
        print "And so on..."
        exit(1)


class Valley(Scene):

    def text(self):

        print "Alternative second scene."
        print "And so on..."
        exit(1)


class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'intro': Intro(),
        'start': Start(),
        'bear': Bear(),
        'valley': Valley(),

        'again': Again(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def open_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map('intro')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

I really hope I've explained myself well, I get stuck in this exercise for days and it seems like I'm not doing no progress at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify `Engine.play` to handle that:

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.text()

if next_scene_name in self.map_scenes.scenes:
    current_scene = self.map_scenes.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```